# C# - Listening to Netflow Routers

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, netflow

I have created a simple UDP Listener console application using C# in order to capture data packets sent from a Netflow v5 router. I have used this Netflow simulator (http://sourceforge.net/projects/netflowsim/)  for my application testing. The application worked fine with the simulator and I was able to read the UDP packets sent from the simulator.

When I used my application to read the packets from the actual Netflow router, my application is unable to read the data. Instead, it keeps listening to the port but there was no data. The application doesn't throw any exception. When I checked the nature of data packets from Wireshark, their protocol is shown as CFlow.

I couldn't find any resources about C# CFlow listeners over Netflow routers. Does anyone has any experience in listening to Netflow routers and CFlow packet receiving?

Comment: What IP, address and port are you listening to? Is the address a unicast or multcast udp(224.x.x.x - 239.x.x.x)?

Comment: IP is in 202.x.x.x range. The port was given as 777 as per specification given by the client

Comment: Port numbers under 1024 are referred to as "Well Known Port Numbers."  See webpage :  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers.  Port 777 is not on the list.  Virus Checkers and Often automatically  block port numbers under 1024 as default settings.  Check your PC and see if port 777 is being blocked.

Comment: Also make sure your firewall is disabled for testing just in case.